# instantiation class before defined

Tags: php, class, instantiation

in php.net the following is written:
Classes should be defined before instantiation (and in some cases this is a requirement).
can anyone give an example when it is required? because a typical use of it doesn't require, like in this example that works ok:

```
<?php
$class = "a" ;
$ob = new $class() ;
class a
{
    var $city = "new york" ;
}
echo $ob->city ;
?>
```

Comment: Could you add a link to where you saw this, so we can see the context?

Comment: Please add link. AFAIK class and function definitions can be anywhere in your file. The interpreter gets all definitions before actually running the file.

Comment: here is the link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work:

```
new Foo;

if (true) {
    class Foo { }
}
```

Conditionally declared classes must come first. Basically, anything that's at the "top level" of the file is handled directly by the parser while parsing the file, which is the step before the runtime environment executes the code (including `new Foo`). However, if a class declaration is nested inside a statement like `if`, this needs to be evaluated by the runtime environment. Even if that statement is guaranteed to be true, the parser cannot evaluate `if (true)`, so the actual declaration of the class is deferred until runtime. And at runtime, if you try to run `new Foo` before `class Foo { }`, it will fail.

Comment: yeah I thought about this scenario too, because I saw this kind of example in functions definition. another scenario that I think is if the class definition is defined inside a function, so in order to instantiate objects of that class, first the function needs to be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

If you call magic method __toString inside your class it generates fatal error : Class "MicroTimer" not found:

```
<?php
$pageTimer = new MicroTimer();

class MicroTimer {
    private $startTime, $stopTime;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->startTime = microtime(true);
    }
    public function stop()
    {
        $this->stopTime = microtime(true);
    }
    public function elapsed()
    {
        if ($this->stopTime)
            return round($this->stopTime - $this->startTime, 4);
        return round(microtime(true) - $this->startTime, 4);
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->elapsed();
    }
}
//$pageTimer = new MicroTimer();
?>
```

If instantiation follows after class definition, it works fine.
Tested with php8.2.
Problem arose in pi os bullseye showing phpLiteAdmin v1.9.8.2 with Google Chrome browser. Can also be seen with command line:
php -f phpliteadmin.php.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a trait inside your class it will through an error:

```php
<?php
$class = "a";
$ob = new $class();

class a {
    var $city = "New York";
    use myTrait;
}
```

I don't know why but that problem have kept me busy for 2 days.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).